# Can't get my one-page website to go underneath each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a one-page website but I can't make the about tab go naturally under the home tab (the picture and the head text and the button) I am trying to make it so you can't scroll till you push the button "learn more". I bet I am making a noob mistake but I just started programming and I hope one of you guys can help me because I can't find the problem. so please help me get the about tab under the "home" page section.

```css
 body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background: #4f4f4f;
 }
 /* home page deco */
 
 .home {
     background: #4f4f4f;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
 }
 
 .backgroundpic {
     background-image: url("http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/58/58/hlVdYW.jpg");
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     height: 93.7%;
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-right: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     margin-top: 30px;
 }
 /* Writing 1 */
 
 .headtext {
     font-family: Open sans;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     display: block;
     color: #fff;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     margin-top: 20%;
     cursor: default;
 }
 
 .header1 {
     font-size: 50px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }
 
 .text1 {
     font-size: 70px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }
 /* button */
 
 .buttonhead {
     font-family: Baloo Bhaijaan;
     margin-left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     padding: 5px;
     color: #FFF;
     float: left;
     border: solid 2px;
     border-radius: 9px;
     font-size: 30px;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .buttonhead:hover {
     color: #ff0000;
 }
 /* nav button */
 
 .navigation {
     display: inline;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-top: 80px;
     margin-right: 120px;
     position: fixed;
     margin-left: 54%
 }
 
 .stripes {
     float: right;
 }
 
 .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
     width: 30px;
     height: 2px;
     background-color: #fff;
     transition: 0.2S;
 }
 
 .bar2, .bar3 {
     margin-top: 7px;
 }
 
 .rotate .bar1 {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     transform: rotate(-45deg) translate( -5px, 7px);
 }
 
 .rotate .bar3 {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg) translate( -6px, -7px);
 }
 
 .rotate .bar2 {
     opacity: 0;
 }
 /* nav locations  */
 
 .navloc {
     display: inline-block;
     color: #fff;
     font-family: Open sans;
     text-align: center;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-right: 30px;
     transition: 0.2S;
     opacity: 0;
 }
 
 .loc {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 30px;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .loc:hover {
     color: #ff0000;
     border-bottom: 2px solid;
     margin-bottom: -2px;
 }
 
 .rotate .navloc {
     opacity: 1;
 }
 /* Writing 2 */
 
 .about {
     font-family: Open sans;
     color: #fff;
 }
 
 .about a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #fff;
     border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, .7);
 }
 
 function rotatebar(x) {
     x.classList.toggle("rotate");
 }
 
 function show(x) {
     x.classList.toggle("showIt");
 }
```

```html
<!--  home div  -->
<div class="home">
    <div class="backgroundpic">
        <!--  navigation button  -->
        <div class="navigation" onclick="rotatebar(this)">
            <div class="navloc">
                <p class="loc">
                    WebDesign
                </p>
                <p class="loc">
                    Photography
                </p>
                <p class="loc">
                    SketchUp
                </p>
                <p class="loc">
                    Photoshop
                </p>
                <p class="loc">
                    About
                </p>
                <p class="loc">
                    Home
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="stripes">
                <div class="bar1">
                </div>
                <div class="bar2">
                </div>
                <div class="bar3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--  text about myself  -->
        <div class="totalheader">
            <div class="headtext">
                <p class="header1">
                    Sup, I'm Lars.
                </p>
                <p class="text1">
                    I do things!
                </p>
            </div>
            <p class="buttonhead" onclick="show(this)">
                click to lear more
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--  scroll page  -->
<div class="about">
    <p>
        I like to explore different programs and try out as many things as I can. I do this so I can make an informed, good and fun career choice! A lot of projects start with me and my friend talking and getting an idea. Eventually we try to make it happen, but sometimes help altogether and sometimes us work together. my goal at the moment is the become a game developer, but I am also interested in game design and internet security. I am not sure what the future holds for me, but in the end, I hope that I'll have a fun job. If you want more info you can contact me at:
        <a href="mailto:larsmulleneers@hotmail.nl">
            Larsmulleneers@hotmail.nl
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: by seeing your requirement i think that until you click on  click to learn more you are not showing the about container is this what you want ?

Comment: yes but it isn't gowing uder the home div so it becomes a scroll it is gowing above the home div in the page making it dissapear isn't the problem but making it gow onder what i have already is